# Unity: Use HTTP PUT in Unity3D

Tags: rest, http, unity-game-engine, put

I'm quite new to Unity and facing some problems about RESTFul in Unity.
I want to update some data on the server by using HTTP PUT, but as what I received when search the web, the WWWW class in Unity doesn't support HTTP PUT. I also tried some HttpWebRequest example related to HTTP PUT but always received error code 400: Bad Request.

How can I solve this problem?
Do I have to list out all the key-value pairs when updating or just need to list the pairs I want to change the value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it worked by the following codes using HttpWebRequest

```
void updatePlayer(){
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://yourAPIUrl");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "{" +
            "'ID': '100'," +
            "'ClubName': 'DEF'," +
            "'Number': 102," +
            "'Name': 'AnNT'," +
            "'Position': 'GK'," +
            "'DateOfBirth': '2010-06-15T00:00:00'," +
            "'PlaceOfBirth': 'Hanoi'," +
            "'Weight': 55," +
            "'Height': 1.55," +
            "'Description': 'des'," +
            "'ImageLink': 'annt.png'," +
            "'Status': false," +
            "'Age': '12'" +
            "}";            
        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        //Now you have your response.
        //or false depending on information in the response
        Debug.Log(responseText);            
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're not looking for a 3rd party plugin and assuming your server supports it then one method you could look at using is the "X-HTTP-Method-Override" HTTP header. Your client sends the data to the server via POST, but the server handles this as the value in the X-HTTP-Method-Override header (such as PUT).

I've used this before to great effect where our server supported it. An example of using this in Unity3d would be along the lines of:

```
string url = "http://yourserver.com/endpoint";
byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);    

Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
headers.Add( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
headers.Add( "X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PUT" );
WWW www = new WWW(url, body, headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at [BestHTTP package](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10872) instead of default WWW class. It's cheap (almost all Unity3d assets are, compared to typical middleware prices in game industry) and it's pretty decent, judging by personal experience.

Alternatively, you can use standard [.NET sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx).

Comment: I also checked BestHTTP but we're student and making capstone project for graduation. With us, that price is a big problem

Comment: Then looks like you'll have to use Sockets. WWW class provided by Unity is pretty basic and is more suited for simple downloads than interfacing with apis.

Comment: For my 2nd question. Do I need to send all the key-value pairs via HTTP PUT or just the pairs I need to update ? Because when I test the API with POSTMAN extension for Chrome, it requires me to fill in all key-value pairs. Error will occur if I list only pair which is need updating